# A use case of null's intentional absence in defining nodejs object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null) of `null` in nodejs:

```
The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values and is treated as falsy for boolean operations.
```

`intentional absence` is my use case. Here is the code:

```
let sqlstring = {
  uploader_id:_uploader_id,  //here _uploader_id is null
  status:_status,  //_status is null
}
```

Based on the definition of `null`, when both _uploader_id and _status have `null`, then  `sqlstring` shall be `{}` because `null` means the value is intentional absence. However the console output has this:

```
sqlstring : {
  uploader_id:null,
  status:null
}
```

What I am expecting is :

```
 sqlstring : {}
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Why would the null properties disappear from an object? That is not how it works. The values are null, that does not mean the object's properties do not exist.

Comment: `{}.status` is unintentional absence. `{status: null}.status` is intentional absence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object can have a member with `null` value, and this looks different from an object where this member is absent. I find the first sentence of the Node.js definition misleading, the second sentence is clearer: `null` is a primitive value, like 0 or 1.

If you write a function that compares two objects, you are free to treat `null` like absence, so that

```js
objectsAreEqual({uploader_id: null, status: null}, {})
```

returns `true`.

Comment: When object `{uploader_id:null, status:null}` is passed to SQL and it was interpreted as `{uploader_id:"null", status:"null"}` and this is mis-interpretation.